# Theoretical Question on Newton Raphson

Tags: optimization, self-learning, newton-raphson

I have a question on Newton Raphson's method. The method is briefly as follows
[image]

Original resource is from https://sites.stat.washington.edu/adobra/classes/536/Files/week1/newtonfull.pdf

My question is why the second order Taylor expression is used instead of first order or  higher order Taylor expression? Can you please share your ideas with me? thank you.

Comment: If you want to find a zero of a function, you use 1st order Taylor expansion.  This algorithm is for finding an extremum in which the derivative is zero so it uses 2nd order Taylor expanion.  If you want to look for a zero of the $n$-th derivative, you'd use an $n+1$-th order Taylor expansion.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. Can you please suggest a book or article or any website resource about my question on the use of 2nd taylor series ? @O.Peters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not seeking the root for the function itself, but for its critical value.

To find min/max we set the derivative to zero i.e, raise differentiation to next order by one more time differentiation.

So we have to subtract for each successive iterate at time of drawing tangent of graph

$$ \dfrac {f'}{f''}\text{ instead of }\dfrac {f}{f'}. $$

Comment: by the way, thank you for your answer

Comment: The Quora ref does not discuss roots of the next derivative.

Comment: okay thank you for your helps

Comment: Dear Narasimham, Can you please suggest a book or article or any website resource about my question on the use of 2nd taylor series ?

Comment: Finding roots of a function  by Newton- Raphson  is mentioned in many standard  literature references. e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method